# Laravel 5.4 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 209715200 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, laravel

I recently cloned a Laravel 5.4 project, run composer install, npm install and gulped. I was able to visit the log in screen of my application fine but of course couldn't log in since there was no database and consequently no users. So I set up the database and imported an sql file of some dummy data for my database. When I tried to log in for the first time the page hung for a bit and then displayed the above error. After that I couldn't even get to the log in screen as it kept displaying that error every time I refreshed. I tried deleting and readding an empty database but I still can't get to the log in screen. I can't even run any artisan commands as I get the same error in the console every time I try.

I've tried upping the `memory_limit` in the php.ini file to no avail, as every action just hangs for longer before displaying the same error message so I feel there must be some sort of infinite loop running somewhere.

I'm finding it quite tough to debug my code as I haven't added any production code, only run composer and npm commands. Any suggestions on how to debug / fix this would be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the error page?

Comment: 200 megabytes for laravel startup.. this is a big number, there is memory leak somewhere or recursion of infinite loop.

Comment: There must be an infinite loop somewhere in your application code. Try adding `dd("here")` around various places to check which parts of your app are reached before crashing.

Comment: Your problem is probably a `$this->register()` in one of your ServiceProviders. It should be `$this->app->register();`.

Comment: Think it was an issue with registering a service provider in the end. Reinstalling the project and fixing some service provider errors in the `config/app.php` file seemed to do the trick